# How to use css file in specific twig file? (working with dropdownlists and subdropdownlists)

Tags: symfony

I would like to use a css file in my edit page for an entity. If I add the css file in my base twig file, the path to the css is wrong, so I added the css file in my edit file :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ asset('css/test.css') }}
{% endblock %}
```

I get no error, but the path to the css file appears at the top of the page and the css does not seem to be working.

The css is :

```
.test {
    background-color :red;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

The javascript adds the class to the parent div of a SELECT :

```
    $('#advert_categories').change(function(v){
        console.log(v.target.value);
        $("#advert_documents").parent().addClass("test");
    });
```

The javascript is correct, when I inspect the code, the class is correctly added to the div.

The goals is to add all the fields at the beginning from my entity in the form with dropdownlist and subdropdowlist, but I hide the subdropdownlists. Then I wait for an option in the parent dropdowlist to be selected.
The goal, for example, is to do : select country > depending on the country : select city, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link href="{{ asset('css/test.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```